# ubuntu 12.04 LTS wireless in Dell Precision T7810

Tags: 12.04, networking, dell

How do I set up wifi for a Dell Precision T7810 running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS unity?
'nm-tool' shows "device eth0, Type: wired," and no other ethernet device.

'sudo lshw -C network' displays "no wireless interface," and
'lspci | grep controller' and 'lsusb' both also show "no wireless."

The dropdown on the menu bar at the top of the unity display shows that "Enable Networking" is checked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Dell Precision T7810 doesn't come with a wireless adapter [according to its spec](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell_Precision_Tower_7810_Spec_Sheet.pdf). So, unless one was added at some point, there's no reason to expect one showing up in Ubuntu's device listings.